# How to write perl agent for windows os

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to develop an agent (preferably in perl ) for windows , that when requested from other host pass on information to requester host.

Are there any API that can be used to serve above purpose ? Is there any recommended way of doing this.

I want to get some expert comments on it,before actually starting it.

Answer (score 2):

Windows won't be a problem with [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) or [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  You can run your program as a service [if you can follow a few easy directions.](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)

When you say "agent" do you mean "network service"?  You can use [`HTTP::Server::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.44/lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm) to do a basic http-based agent, or if you want to build your own protocol you can always use [`IO::Socket::INET`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm).

Ultimately it depends on what kind of "agent" you need, and how you want to access the agent.

Comment: By "agent", I mean the communication should obviously happen over network. As far as accessing agent is concerned, I am interested to build a website that gathers specific information from windows host using this agent. Which of the method do you feel more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Should be fairly straightforward to use the `HTTP::Server::Simple` to build a small web responder which you could use to gather data on the hosts, assuming the data you need can be gathered by perl.